# Solving finite and infinite nested square roots of 2 - yet another interesting approach

Tags: trigonometry, integers, fibonacci-numbers, geometric-series, nested-radicals

Consider the following consecutive equalities:

$\sqrt2=2\cos(\frac{1}{4})\pi$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}=2\cos(\frac{3}{8})\pi$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}=2\cos(\frac{5}{16})\pi$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}=2\cos(\frac{11}{32})\pi$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}}=2\cos(\frac{21}{64})\pi$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}}}=2\cos(\frac{43}{128})\pi$

**Here is the beautiful part**

$\frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}$

$\frac{5}{16} = \frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{16}$ = $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}$

$\frac{11}{32} = \frac{5}{16}+\frac{1}{32}$ = $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}$

$\frac{21}{64} = \frac{11}{32}-\frac{1}{64}$ = $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}-\frac{1}{64}$

$\frac{43}{128} = \frac{21}{64}+\frac{1}{128}$ = $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}-\frac{1}{64}+\frac{1}{128}$

If extended to infinity $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2...}}} = 2cos(\frac{1}{3})\pi$ (we can calculate the sum of infinite Geometric progression and we get there result as $1\over3$)

We can easily guess that if a nested square root has $n$ $2$’s then a denominator of the corresponding cosine argument is $2^{n+1}$.

**Most beautiful part is getting the numerator which is $2^{n+1} \over 3$ approximated to nearest integer.[or approximation to floor and making it as very next odd number(if the floor is even number)--> and this is better ]**

Subsequent numbers having numerator are as follows

$\frac{2^3}{3}=3;\frac{2^4}{3}=5;\frac{2^5}{3}=11;\frac{2^6}{3}=21;\frac{2^7}{3}=43;\frac{2^8}{3}=85;\frac{2^9}{3}=171;\frac{2^{10}}{3}=341...$

**Therefore for the finite number of nested square roots of 2 like this, it is the easy way to evaluate the angle inside the cosine function!**

One more exciting part is association with integer sequence of type [Jacobsthal sequence](https://oeis.org/A001045) $a(n-1) + 2a(n-2)$, with $a(0) = 0, a(1) = 1$.

Still more interesting part is Fibonacci like pattern from above integer sequence

> **My question is can we link geometric progression to simplify different patterns of the finite or infinite nested square roots of 2, like this?**

**To expand my question to understand**

Let us consider finite nested square roots of 2 in simplified way

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}$ as $n\sqrt2(1-)$ and $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}$ as $n\sqrt2(1-1+)$

If we have finite nested square roots of 2 such as $n\sqrt2(1-2+)$ repeated signs inside nested radical 'n' times and infinitely, how can we get the angle?. What I have shown is simplest example. Let us consider $n\sqrt2(3-1+7-)$ or $n\sqrt2(2-3+4-1+)$ and so on. Is there any easier way to find the cosine angle?

Comment: I think your right parentheses are misplaced in your first list of formulas : $\cos(\frac{1}{4})\pi$ should be $\cos\big(\frac{1}{4}\pi \big)$, $\cos(\frac{3}{8})\pi$ should be $\cos\big(\frac{3}{8}\pi\big)$, etc.

Comment: Of course. In that way also can be expressed. To just make the fractions inside the cosine arguments "more obvious" to the interested persons who are reading this post.

Answer (score 5):

I don't quite understand the phrasing of your question, and in particular I don't quite understand if you're asking for a proof of these identities or not. Here is a proof. We can reverse-engineer the result we need by asking what relation between two angles $\alpha_n, \alpha_{n+1}$ is implied by

$$\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos \alpha_n} = 2 \cos \alpha_{n+1};$$

here $\alpha_n$ and $\alpha_{n+1}$ are two consecutive angles among the sequence of angles you've listed. Squaring and using the cosine double-angle formula $\cos 2 \theta = 2 \cos^2 \theta - 1$ gives

$$2 - 2 \cos \alpha_n = 4 \cos^2 \alpha_{n+1} = 2 + 2 \cos 2 \alpha_{n+1}$$

which gives $\cos \alpha_n = - \cos 2 \alpha_{n+1}$. If $\alpha_i \in \left[ 0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$, which holds for all of your angles, then this gives

$$\alpha_{n+1} = \frac{\pi - \alpha_n}{2}.$$

It's not hard to see that this generates all of the angles you've listed, starting from $\alpha_0 = \frac{\pi}{4}$, and that this sequence converges to the unique fixed point $\alpha_{\infty} = \frac{\pi}{3}$ of the map $\alpha \mapsto \frac{\pi - \alpha}{2}$. We have the explicit closed form

$$\alpha_n = \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{12} \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right)^n$$

which can be proven by rewriting the recurrence relation as $\alpha_{n+1} - \frac{\pi}{3} = \left( \alpha_n - \frac{\pi}{3} \right) \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right)$. Adding these two fractions gives

$$\alpha_n = \left( \frac{2^{n+2} - (-1)^n}{3 \cdot 2^{n+2}} \right) \pi$$

and then we note that $2^{n+2} \equiv (-1)^{n+2} \equiv (-1)^n \bmod 3$ so the numerator is always divisible by $3$, and dividing it by $3$ gives $\frac{2^{n+2} - (-1)^n}{3}$ which is the closest integer to $\frac{2^{n+2}}{3}$ as you observed.

Comment: Amazing explanation.  But I'm not able to understand from the explicit closed form. $$\alpha_{n}=\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{12}(\frac{1}{2})^n$$

Comment: @Sivakumar: you mean you don't understand how to prove it? Basically the point is that the recurrence is a slight variation on a linear recurrence $a_{n+1} = r a_n$, with just a constant term added. That turns out to imply that the solution is a slight variation on an exponential, with just a constant term added. You can prove this pretty straightforwardly by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of consecutive nested square roots of $2$, that is $a_n=\sqrt{2\pm a_{n-1}}$ for each $n\ge n_0$.
Assuming $a_{n-1}=2\cos x_{n-1}$ for $x_{n-1}\in [0,\pi]$, we obtain $a_n=2\cos x_n$, where $x_n=x_{n-1}/2$, if  $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$ and $x_n=(\pi-x_{n-1})/2$, if $a_n=\sqrt{2-a_{n-1}}$. This way the sequence of signs transforms to a sequence of angles. The latter looks close to a geometric series only in special cases. When all signs are “$+$” then $\{x_n\}$ is a geometric series. When all signs are “$-$ then $(\pi/3-x_n)=-(\pi/3-x_{n-1})/2$. That is, $\{\pi/3-x_n\}$ is a geometric series.

Comment: $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+...}}}}}}$ also can give rise to geometric series. Any kind of repetition like $a-b+c-d+$ and so on for x terms and infinite repetition of x terms can produce geometric series.