# Golden ratio, cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 and and Geometric progression and cosine value

Tags: trigonometry, modular-arithmetic, integers, nested-radicals, golden-ratio

In connection to previous posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952080/cosine-angles-and-finite-nested-square-roots-of-2?noredirect=1#comment8151643_3952080) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3937457/solving-finite-and-infinite-nested-square-roots-of-2-yet-another-interesting-a)now we know $2\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}$ can be represented as $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+...}}$ simply represented as $cin\sqrt2[1-1+]$ and this converges to inverse of golden ratio $\frac{1}{\phi}$[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841604/solving-cyclic-infinite-nested-square-roots-of-2-as-cosine-functions/3841605#3841605)

Let us examine the finite radicals

$\sqrt2 = 2\cos\frac{1}{4}\pi$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt2} = 2\cos\frac{3}{2^3}\pi$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}$ ==> $n\sqrt2(1-1+)$ = $2\cos\frac{7}{2^4}\pi$

$n\sqrt2(1-1+1-)$ = $2\cos\frac{13}{2^5}\pi$

$n\sqrt2(1-1+1-1+)$ = $2\cos\frac{25}{2^6}\pi$

$n\sqrt2(1-1+1-1+1-)$ = $2\cos\frac{51}{2^7}\pi$

$n\sqrt2(1-1+1-1+1-1-)$ = $2\cos\frac{103}{2^8}\pi$

Let us analyse the angle pattern observed in Geometric progression approach

$\frac{3}{2^3}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}$

$\frac{7}{2^4}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}$

$\frac{13}{2^5}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}- \frac{1}{2^5}$

$\frac{25}{2^5}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}- \frac{1}{2^5}- \frac{1}{2^6}$

If we explore further we can observe a pattern as $++--$ of $2^{-n}$ after $\frac{1}{4}$

In this series again interesting pattern of getting numerator is as follows

$\frac{2^3}{5}$ = $1+\frac{3}{5}$ ( $1$ is the numerator)

$\frac{2^4}{5}$ = $3+\frac{1}{5}$ ( $3$ is the numerator)

$\frac{2^5}{5}$ = $6+\frac{2}{5}$ ( $6+1 = 7$ is the numerator)

$\frac{2^6}{5}$ = $12+\frac{4}{5}$ ( $12+1 = 13$ is the numerator)

$\frac{2^7}{5}$ = $25+\frac{3}{5}$ ( $25$ is the numerator)

$\frac{2^8}{5}$ = $51+\frac{1}{5}$ ( $51$ is the numerator)

$\frac{2^9}{5}$ = $102+\frac{2}{5}$ ( $102+1 = 103$ is the numerator) and so on

> **Summing infinite Geometric series clearly results in $\frac{2}{5}$ which is amazing and $cin\sqrt2[1-1+] = 2\cos\frac{2}{5}\pi$**

**Astonishingly modulo of 5 with respect to $2^n$ exactly predicts the sign for the component of the geometric series**

$2^3 \equiv 3 \pmod 5 $

$2^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5 $

$2^5 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 $

$2^6 \equiv 4 \pmod 5 $

Subsequently it repeats. Here important thing to observe is odd number modulo translates to $+$ sign and even number modulo translates to $-$ sign in Geometric series.

**Therefore just by taking modulo for $2^n$ of any odd number(like 5 in this case) we can predict the pattern of geometric series with respect to $2^{-n}$ in deriving the result of cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2**

It is exciting to know that the numerator sequence is associated with integer sequence of Expansion of $\frac{(1-x+2x^2)}{((1-2x)(1+x^2))}$ [this](https://oeis.org/A190569) type. But I don't know this kind of expansion how it is done to get integer sequences. Please explain

*Please help me to express the infinite Geometric series in some better way in summation notation. (Even previous one also)*